# sort , grouping and sum of nodes basing sort?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

```
 <fo:block start-indent="5mm">  
    <xsl:for-each select="//policyResult[not(AgentNumber=preceding-sibling::policyResult/AgentNumber)]" >    
    <xsl:variable name="agentNum"><xsl:value-of select="AgentNumber"></xsl:value-of>  
    </xsl:variable>                 
    <xsl:for-each select="//policyResult[AgentNumber=$agentNum]">    
<xsl:sort select="agentnumber"/>
<xsl:sort select="policynumber"/>
    <fo:table border-style="" width="100%" border-spacing="4">                          
    <fo:table-body>    
    <fo:table-row border-before-style="solid">   
    <fo:table-cell>   
    <fo:block>
           <fo:inline>Pol Number</fo:inline><xsl:value-of select="PolicyNumber"/>    
    </fo:block>    
    </fo:table-cell>        
    </fo:table-body>    
    </fo:table>
```

i written some code like this to filter the nodes which are repeated.
here my problem is i have to sort this in ascending order.the xml looks like this

```
    <policyResult xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.faithlife.com/resonant">
                                   <producttype>risk</producttype>                            <PolicyNumber>003050669</PolicyNumber>    
                    <AgentNumber>005262</AgentNumber>
                    <AnnualPremium>12000.0</AnnualPremium>                  
    </policyResult>
    <policyResult xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.faithlife.com/resonant">
<producttype>wealth</producttype>                   
<PolicyNumber>003050669</PolicyNumber>
                    <AgentNumber>005282</AgentNumber>
                    <AnnualPremium>12000.0</AnnualPremium>                  
    </policyResult>

    <policyResult xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.faithlife.com/resonant">
<producttype>risk</producttype>
                    <PolicyNumber>003050670</PolicyNumber>
                    <AgentNumber>005262</AgentNumber>
                    <AnnualPremium>12000.0</AnnualPremium>      

    </policyResult>
    <policyResult xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.faithlife.com/resonant">
<producttype>wealth</producttype>
                    <PolicyNumber>003050671</PolicyNumber>
                    <AgentNumber>005263</AgentNumber>
                    <AnnualPremium>12000.0</AnnualPremium>                      
    </policyResult>
    <policyResult xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.faithlife.com/resonant">
<producttype>wealth</producttype>
                    <PolicyNumber>003050668</PolicyNumber>
                    <AgentNumber>005265</AgentNumber>
                    <AnnualPremium>12000.0</AnnualPremium>                  
    </policyResult>
    <policyResult xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.faithlife.com/resonant">
<producttype>wealth</producttype>
                    <PolicyNumber>003050668</PolicyNumber>
                    <AgentNumber>005265</AgentNumber>
                    <AnnualPremium>12000.0</AnnualPremium>                  
    </policyResult>
```

what i have to do is filter the AgentNumber ,AnnualPremium in ascending order.and need sum the Annualpremium of each agent and sum of all Annualpremium.

the out put should be like this.
if the agent 
number repeats we have to show it only once in ascending order

product type: risk

agent number 005266

policynumber 003050669
anuual premium 12000

policynumber 003050671
anuual premium 12000

total annual premium  --sum of premium of this agent i.e 24000

agent number 005267

policynumber 0001234
anuual premium 11000

policynumber 0001235
anuual premium 11000
total annual premium  --sum of premium of this agent i.e 22000

product type: wealth

agent number 005266

policynumber 003050669
anuual premium 12000

policynumber 003050671
anuual premium 12000

total annual premium  --sum of premium of this agent i.e 24000

agent number 005267

policynumber 0001234
anuual premium 11000

policynumber 0001235
anuual premium 11000
total annual premium  --sum of premium of this agent i.e 22000

at the end we need to display overall annual premium of all the agents

total premiums---24000+22000=46000

please help me out..thanks in advance

need this kind of output..

Answer (score 0):

Again, your input data does not match your expected results.  Today I do not have the time to correct your input data, but I have written a transformation that would work with corrected data.  I have run it with the data you have given me.

In your new XSLT 1.0 requirement for nested grouping, I find using the variable-based grouping method to be the easiest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="policies">
  <xsl:variable name="types" select="policyResult"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$types">
    <xsl:sort select="producttype"/>
    <xsl:if test="generate-id(.)=
                  generate-id($types[producttype=current()/producttype][1])">
Product type: <xsl:value-of select="producttype"/>
      <xsl:variable name="agents"
                    select="$types[producttype=current()/producttype]"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$agents">
        <xsl:sort select="AgentNumber"/>
        <xsl:if test="generate-id(.)=
                   generate-id($agents[AgentNumber=current()/AgentNumber][1])">
Agent number: <xsl:value-of select="AgentNumber"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="$agents[AgentNumber=current()/AgentNumber]">
Policy number: <xsl:value-of select="PolicyNumber"/> Premium: <xsl:value-of
                             select="AnnualPremium"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
Agent premium total: <xsl:value-of
      select="sum($agents[AgentNumber=current()/AgentNumber]/AnnualPremium)"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
Premium total: <xsl:value-of select="sum( policyResult/AnnualPremium )"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the stylesheet is applied to the following XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<policies>
  <policyResult xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.faithlife.com/resonant">
    <producttype>risk</producttype>
    <PolicyNumber>003050669</PolicyNumber>
    <AgentNumber>005262</AgentNumber>
    <AnnualPremium>12000.0</AnnualPremium>
  </policyResult>
  <policyResult xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.faithlife.com/resonant">
    <producttype>wealth</producttype>
    <PolicyNumber>003050669</PolicyNumber>
    <AgentNumber>005282</AgentNumber>
    <AnnualPremium>12000.0</AnnualPremium>
  </policyResult>
  <policyResult xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.faithlife.com/resonant">
    <producttype>risk</producttype>
    <PolicyNumber>003050670</PolicyNumber>
    <AgentNumber>005262</AgentNumber>
    <AnnualPremium>12000.0</AnnualPremium>
  </policyResult>
  <policyResult xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.faithlife.com/resonant">
    <producttype>wealth</producttype>
    <PolicyNumber>003050671</PolicyNumber>
    <AgentNumber>005263</AgentNumber>
    <AnnualPremium>12000.0</AnnualPremium>
  </policyResult>
  <policyResult xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.faithlife.com/resonant">
    <producttype>wealth</producttype>
    <PolicyNumber>003050668</PolicyNumber>
    <AgentNumber>005265</AgentNumber>
    <AnnualPremium>12000.0</AnnualPremium>
  </policyResult>
  <policyResult xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.faithlife.com/resonant">
    <producttype>wealth</producttype>
    <PolicyNumber>003050668</PolicyNumber>
    <AgentNumber>005265</AgentNumber>
    <AnnualPremium>12000.0</AnnualPremium>
  </policyResult>
</policies>
```

**It produces the following output:**

```
Product type: risk
Agent number: 005262
Policy number: 003050669 Premium: 12000.0
Policy number: 003050670 Premium: 12000.0
Agent premium total: 24000
Product type: wealth
Agent number: 005263
Policy number: 003050671 Premium: 12000.0
Agent premium total: 12000
Agent number: 005265
Policy number: 003050668 Premium: 12000.0
Policy number: 003050668 Premium: 12000.0
Agent premium total: 24000
Agent number: 005282
Policy number: 003050669 Premium: 12000.0
Agent premium total: 12000
Premium total: 72000
```